# $r(X) = r(P_{X}) = \text{tr}(P_X)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, generalized-inverse

I would like to prove $r(X) = r(P_{X}) = \text{tr}(P_X)$, $r$ denoting the rank, $X \in M_{n \times p}(\mathbb{R})$, and $$P_{X} = X(X^{T}X)^{-}X^{T}$$
where $(X^{T}X)^{-}$ is a [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) of $X^{T}X$.

I don't believe I know the machinery to prove this. But here's what I do know that might possibly be relevant.:

1. $P_X$ is symmetric. So therefore, the trace of $P_X$ is the sum of its eigenvalues. This suggests to me that the sum of its eigenvalues is also its rank (for whatever reason).
2. I have a feeling that the Singular Value Decomposition is involved. But I have no idea how to use this nor am I familiar with its properties (I am completely self-taught when it comes to SVD).

An explanation of how to pursue this proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\text{tr}[X(X^TX)^{-}X^T] = \text{tr}[X^TX(X^TX)^{-}]$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 So the trace of $P_{X}$ is equal to the trace of the identity $I_{p \times p}$?

Comment: That's true if $X^TX$ is full rank. Otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I must be missing something here... what *is* $X^{T}X(X^{T}X)^{-}$ when $X^{T}X$ isn't full rank?

Comment: $P_X$ is an orthogonal projection onto the span of $X$.  With this information alone, we have enough information to use the eigenvalues of $P_X$ to find the trace and rank of $P_X$ in terms of the rank of $X$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Okay, using the approach you've suggested, I know that the eigenvalues of $P_{X}$ have to be either $0$ or $1$, so the trace is going to be some number less than or equal to $p$ (since $P_{X} \in M_{p \times p}(\mathbb{R})$). What more can I do with this idea? Obviously if $X$ is invertible, this is easy. But if $X$ isn't?

Comment: $P_X$ is diagonalizable, so the rank is the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = U\Sigma V^T$ be the SVD of $X$, where $\Sigma$ is $n\times p$. Then

$$
X^TX = V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T
$$

is the SVD of $X^TX$. Hence, $(X^TX)^- = V(\Sigma^T\Sigma)^-V^T$. It follows that

$$
P_X = X(X^TX)^-X^T = U\Sigma(\Sigma^T\Sigma)^-\Sigma^T U^T = U
\left [
\begin{array}{cc}
I_{r\times r} & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right ]
U^T
$$

is the SVD of $P_X$. The desired equalities should now follow readily.

Comment: One question: how did you get $(X^{T}X)^{-} = V(\Sigma^{T}\Sigma)^{-}V^{T}$? I tried working through it:$$(X^{T}X)^{-} = (V\Sigma^{T}\Sigma V^{T})^{-} = (V^{T})^{-}(\Sigma ^{T}\Sigma)^{-}V^{-} = \text{ ?}$$

Comment: If $A = U\Sigma V^T$ is the SVD of a matrix $A$, then the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$ is defined as $A^- = V\Sigma^- U^T$.

Comment: Whoa... that is news to me. I am used to the $AA^{-}A = A$ definition for $A^{-}$ a generalized inverse and can see how you got the $A^{-}$ equation now. So now I understand your work. By "commutativity" of trace, we have that $\text{tr}(P_{X}) = r$. How do I know this is equal to $r(P_{X})$? I know that $U$ is unitary, but nothing beyond that.

Comment: Another nice feature of the SVD is that the number of nonzero entries in the diagonal matrix is equal to the rank of the matrix. In this way the SVD is said to be rank revealing. Thus $r(P_X) = r = r(X)$. The trace result also follows by the fact that similar matrices have the same trace.